# Create a new variable which count length of duplicate in R

Tags: r, count, duplicates, aggregate

I have a data frame,I want to create a variable z,count duplicate of "y variable", if y have 1,1 set z = 2,2, if y have 3,3,3, set z = 3,3,3.

```
 x = c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c")
 y = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
 data <- data.frame(x,y)
 data
    x y z
 1  a 1 2
 2  b 1 2
 3  c 2 3
 4  d 2 3
 5  e 2 3
 6  a 3 2
 7  b 3 2
 8  c 4 3
 9  d 4 3
 10 e 4 3
 11 a 5 3
 12 b 5 3
 13 c 5 3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what if y is `1 1 2 1 3 3` is z `3 3 1 3 2 2` or `2 2 1 1 2 2`?

Comment: if y is 1 1 2 1 3 3 , z will be 2 2 1 1 2 2, but y I set unique, so it doesn't have random, y is seq of increasing number

Comment: Actually y variable y = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `rle`:

```
data$z <- with(data, unlist(mapply(rep, rle(y)$lengths, rle(y)$lengths)))
data
   x y z
1  a 1 2
2  b 1 2
3  c 2 3
4  d 2 3
5  e 2 3
6  a 3 2
7  b 3 2
8  c 4 3
9  d 4 3
10 e 4 3
11 a 5 3
12 b 5 3
13 c 5 3
```

Comment: Which part you think is not correct? Just note that you cut your data at 30, so the last `11, 11` can not really count, there might be another 11 after that.

Answer (score 2):

If your your variable y is sorted as an increasing sequence as you say, then the following solution will work:

```
# calculate counts of each level
counts <- table(data$y)
# fill in z
data$z <- counts[match(data$y, names(counts))]
```

Note, however, that *this method will fail* if y is not ordered and, since you want to restart the count when a different level occurs.  For these purposes, @psidom's solution is more robust to mis-ordered data as `rle` will reset the count.

This method calculates the total occurrences of a level and then feeds these total counts to the proper location using `match`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick method using dplyr, and its rather intuitive syntax:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(data, data %>%
                group_by(y) %>%
                summarize(z = n()), 
          by = "y")

   x y z
1  a 1 2
2  b 1 2
3  c 2 3
4  d 2 3
5  e 2 3
6  a 3 2
7  b 3 2
8  c 4 3
9  d 4 3
10 e 4 3
11 a 5 3
12 b 5 3
13 c 5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, z := .N , rleid(y)]
data
#    x y z
# 1: a 1 2
# 2: b 1 2
# 3: c 2 3
# 4: d 2 3
# 5: e 2 3
# 6: a 3 2
# 7: b 3 2
# 8: c 4 3
# 9: d 4 3
#10: e 4 3
#11: a 5 3
#12: b 5 3
#13: c 5 3
```

---

Or using `rle` from `base R` without any `loops`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(data$y), values <- lengths))
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

Or another base R method with `ave`

```
with(data, ave(y, cumsum(c(TRUE, y[-1]!= y[-length(y)])), FUN=length))
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
```